# How does the Soundness Theorem follow from this lemma?

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory

The soundness theorem is a famous theorem in logic that goes like this:

> If $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, then $\Gamma \vDash \phi$.

It's supposed to follow readily from Lemma 3.2.3 from Moerdijk/Van Oosten's [Sets, Models and Proofs](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/%7Eooste110/syllabi/setsproofs09.pdf):

> *Lemma 3.2.3* Suppose $T$ is an $L$-labelled proof tree with unmarked assumptions $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n$ and conclusion $\psi$; let $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ be a list of all varialbes that are free in at least one of $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n,\psi$. Then for every $L$-structure $M$ and any $k$-tuple $m_1,\ldots,m_k$ of elements of $M$, we have:
>
> If for all $i, 1\le i\le n, M \models\phi_i[m_1/u_1,\ldots,m_k/u_k]$, then $M \models\psi[m_1/u_1,\ldots,m_k/u_k]$.

Can anyone explain to me why that is?

Comment: What book (title, author, etc.) is the lemma from?

Comment: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/setsproofs09.pdf

Comment: Are you clear about the definitions of the two "turnstile" symbols and the meaning of the claim in your "soundness theorem"?

Comment: Hint: to solve Exercise 91 in those nice notes, observe that it comes just after a section entitled "Induction on Proof Trees".

Comment: @hardmath, yes I'm studying those concepts right now. And I'll try induction, see where it takes me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *soundness* property of a *logical calculus* means that if a *formula* $\phi$ is *derivable* form the set $\Gamma$ of *premises* (or *assumptions*) :

> $\Gamma \vdash \phi$,

then $\phi$ is a *logical consequence* of the premises in $\Gamma$, according to the *semantics* suitable for that *calculus* :

> $\Gamma \vDash \phi$.

---

The application of the said *Lemma* is roughly this; let $\Gamma = \{ \varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n \}$ the set of *assumptions* and let $\psi$ the conclusion of the *derivation* (the *proof tree*) [see page 81 of your lecture notes].

We assume that, for any *structure* $M$ "suitable" for the language $L$ [see page 42 of your lecture notes], the premises are all *true* (or *satisfied*) in $M$ : $M \vDash \varphi_i$ [see page 43].

The *rules* of the calculus are defined exactly in a way to be *sound*, i.e. such that if the premises of the rules are true (in a strucutre $M$) so is the conclusion [this is the gist of the proof of the *Lemma*, page 88, where some rules are treated in detail].

Thus, any step in the derivation "transfer" truth from the previous one and thus, if all the premises in $\Gamma$ are *true* in $M$, so is the conclusion $\psi$ : $M \vDash \psi$.

But this is exactly the definition of *logical consequence* : $\Gamma \vDash \psi$ [see page 50].

---

See e.g :

- Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA67) (5th ed - 2013), page 67 :

> We say that $\varphi$ is a *semantic consequence* of $\Gamma$ if $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, i.e. $\varphi$ holds in each model of $\Gamma$ [where : $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$ ϕ iff (if $M \vDash \Gamma$, then $M \vDash \varphi$)].

Comment: Wow! I know you're not supposed to say "thank you" in the comments, but this answer is just too good, so I have to say it: Thank you, Mauro!

Answer (score 1):

Mauro's answer is very helpful and clear.  I'd just like to add to it one point.

Granted the context of the lemma you mention, that lemma isn't just a restatement of soundness but a slight generalization.

Recall that, roughly speaking, soundness says that derivability implies consequence.  However, this rough statement is not strictly true for some systems which are intuitively sound.  The reason is that derivability may relate formulas with free variables, whereas consequence, as its construed in the notes, applies only to formulas which are true-or-false in a structure, which is to say closed formulas.

As Mauro says, "$\psi$ is a consequence of $\Gamma$" means there's no $M$ such that $M\models \Gamma$ but $M\not\models \psi$.  So, and I think this is how it's construed in the cited notes, consequence is a relation on formulas which are true-or-false in an arbitrary structure for the language. For example, $Fx$ will not even be a consequence of $Fx$.  Rather, if a formula $\phi$ contains free variables $u_1,\ldots,u_k$, then it is true in $M$ only relative to a substitution $m_1/u_1\ldots,m_k/u_k$ of constants-from-$M$ for those variables.

On the other hand, derivability is a relation on arbitrary formulas.  For example, $Fx$ is certainly derivable from $Fx$.  Thus, $Fx$ is derivable from itself but not a consequence of itself, and the rough statement of soundness fails.

Happily, consequence can be generalized a notion of free-variable consequence, which applies to open formulas.

$\psi$ is a *free-variable consequence* of $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_k$ iff for every $M$ and every $M$-substitution $m_1/u_1,\ldots,m_k/u_k$ for $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ we have that $M\models\psi[m_1/u_1,\ldots,m_k/u_k]$ whenever $M\models \phi_i[m_1/u_1,\ldots,m_k/u_k]$ for all $i$.

Now, the lemma you mention says:  "derivability implies free-variable consequence".  When "derivability implies consequence" is restricted to closed formulas, it follows immediately from the lemma.

(The need to pass through a special free-variable notion of consequence turns a bit on then notes' choice of a Shoenfield-style rather than Tarskian semantics for the quantifiers.)

Comment: It seems to me that $F(x) \vdash F(x)$ and also $F(x) \vDash F(x)$, so the example mentioned is not clear to me. Perhaps you have a different convention about what it means for a model to satisfy a formula with free variables? But, whatever $M \vDash F(x)$ means, it seems to me that if $M \vDash F(x)$ then $M \vDash F(x)$, so $F(x)$ should be a consequence of itself.

Comment: Many authors include a variable substitution as part of a model $M$, so that for every formula $\phi$ we have $M \vDash \phi$ or $M \vDash \lnot \phi$. Perhaps the example was coming from the other perspective where $\vDash$ is only defined for sentences?

Comment: Yes, on a Tarski-style understanding of consequence, then $Fx$ is a consequence of itself, so soundness and derivability coincide.  But I was hoping to follow the convention of the [notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/setsproofs09.pdf).  So construed, a model doesn't satisfy a formula with free variables absolutely, but only relative to a replacement of those variables with parameters.  In contrast, the consequence as explained on page 50 doesn't relativize truth to a notion of replacement.

Comment: At least according to the definitions of structure and of truth on pages 42-43, it looks like a variable-substitution isn't built into a structure.